# CSS first-child and div with class name doesn't work

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've wrote this in HTML:

```
<div> hello</div>
<div class="name"><p>hello</p></div>
<div class="name"><p>hello</p></div>
```

and this in CSS:

```
div.name:first-child{
  color: red;
}
```

I would like to change text color of second 'hello' to red. But it doesn't work. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: `:first-child` does just that, selects the first child element. Since you made this selector *more restrictive* by providing a class, it won't match. Whenever you add a CSS class to a pseudo-class it makes it act like a filter.

Comment: `<div class="name">` should have parent div then only first-child will work

Answer (score 2):

it's the second child, not the first, use `nth-child`:

```css
div.name:nth-child(2){
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div> hello</div>
<div class="name"><p>hello</p></div>
<div class="name"><p>hello</p></div>
```

Comment: True, but I have a feeling the OP wants to select the first div with the class name and it might not always be the second child.

Comment: I think you're right. In which case, there's no easy pure css solution that I know of, but `document.querySelector(".name").style.color = "red"` would work.

Comment: sweaver2112 This js script look good for me. Now I exercise only css, but thank you for another point of view. It will be halpful in the future.

@j08691 - yes, you have a good feeling :)

And what do you think about this solution: 

HTML:

`<div class="name red"><p>hello</p></div>
<div class="name red"><p>hello</p></div>
 <div class="name red"><p>hello</p></div>`

CSS:
`.red{
color:red;
}`

It is correct?

Comment: I think that's perfectly valid example of "semantic CSS", which is a good thing. Far better than using the (sure to change) structure of the HTML.